# How to find non-printable character in text file

Tags: file, binary

I have a text file that is processed by a third party. They told me the file is invalid because it contains a non-printable character. What's the best way to find the non-printable character as my normal text editors won't display it. I would prefer a windows, dos, or powershell based solution.

Comment: Google is your friend...

Comment: yep, tried and found utils, but none found the binary character.

Comment: binary-search is not the tag you're looking for.

Comment: I assume you mean "non-printable character". "Binary character" doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: Um,why down vote w/o comment??

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta - yes, that's probably more accurate.

Comment: @BillMartin - I wasn't the downvoter, but I'd guess it's because *all* characters in every file are "binary" at some level.

Comment: @DaveRager - yes, it's ascii. What do you mean  'most significant bit set'?

Comment: If it's plain ASCII, look for the byte greater than or equal to 128, or less than 32.

Comment: @BaliC - unfortunately, now Google shows this page as the top response to the question :-/

Comment: How can I vote to re-open this question?

Comment: For me, Unix not Windows, I got a solution here ; http://www.unixcl.com/2009/10/grep-and-print-control-characters-in.html . Several methods are listed, but what worked for me to fix python bug PEP 0263 on pasted code was showing entire file : "$ cat -v -e -t /tmp/s "

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Option #1 - Show All Characters

You can download [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and open the file there. Then, go to the menu and select `View->Show Symbol->Show All Characters`. All characters will become visible, but you will have to scroll through the whole file to see which character needs to be removed.

Unfortunately, [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) will automatically convert line endings according to your `Edit->EOL Conversion` selection, so it won't help if your non-printable characters are CR or LF.

#### Option #2 - TextFX Zap Non-printable Chars

Alternatively, you could install the TextFX plugin from SourceForge, and use `TextFX->TextFX Characters->Zap all non-printable characters to #`. This will replace some non-printable characters with a pound sign, but not CR or LF.

#### Option #3 - Remove BOM Encoding

Lastly, you could use Notepad++, and use `Encoding->Convert to UTF8 without BOM`. This will remove non-printable characters which occasionally causes issues with certain renderers ([VSO](http://visualstudio.com)).

Comment: Please note : Unfortunately, "Zap all non printable characters" also targets characters with diacritics, like 'é'.

Comment: Note `UTF-8 Without BOM is now just called UTF-8` https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/7409/utf-8-without-bom-option

Comment: Note: in my case, Notepad++ did not show the characters, even with `Show all Characters` (Option #1).  I had to use `od -c` on Linux, or `vi` to see them.  Their ASCII representation was "357 273 277" or "\ufeff; ", at the very beginning of my file.  However converting it to UTF-8 with Notepad++ worked and removed these (Option #3).

Comment: As of ver. 8.4.2, Notepad++ shows CR/LF when you select Show All Characters