# Textfile in Excel

Tags: excel, text

Does anyone know why Excel 2013 is posting  the last number in the row below when I paste this text in a cell ; 
**075680 TYSNES                    95759753
                   95759753**

Comment: If you have certain non-printing characters in your input, Excel will interpret them. Newline is one such character. It has no visual representation, but when text editors see it, they start putting text on the next line. This is handy with tabs in Excel. If you copy your example text from this page I bet it goes into one cell because the non-printing chars get stripped out.

Comment: Do you know how I can remove the non-printing characters before I import the textile to Excel ?

Comment: There's no uniform way. Making sure you're not selecting more than one line at a time will prevent the error you're seeing.

Comment: My problem is that I am importing the text file with a data connection and the non-printing characters must be removed before importing into Excel? Otherwise a get an additional row that is not connected to the row above

Comment: So you want me to tell you how to fix your mystery import process?

Comment: Yes :) Data source is a text file with raw data located locally and in Excel I have a macro that imports the data into column A

Answer (score 0):

Paste it without the previous format rules:
try to:

- go in insertion mode (double click on your target cell)
- Paste the content using the short cut "ctrl+shift+v"

In order to clean-up your data source from non-printable characters there are already some question about it. I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522930/how-to-find-non-printable-character-in-text-file) can explain everything you need. I can simply replace all of them with nothing and that's it.

Comment: Do you know how I can remove the non-printing characters before I import the textile to Excel ?

Comment: Have you tried the paste without format short cut? I have tried on my pc and for me it trims my statement (meaning that if there is a tab it becomes only a space e not a lot of space). So maybe can work with you problem too

Comment: My problem is that I am importing the text file with a data connection and the non-printing characters must be removed before importing into Excel? Otherwise a get an additional row that is not connected to the row above

Comment: And how you handle those data? Are you downloading a file or something? You need to be more specific on the data source.

Comment: Data source is a text file with raw data located locally and in Excel I have a macro that imports the data into column A.

Comment: Please do not link to answers without explaining the relevant portions and properly citing the source if you quote it.